# Multiple entity relationship mapping fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

This is a part of my entity-relationship model: 
[image: ER diagram]

I found few ways to map the 'It' relationship:
**[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974879/three-way-many-to-many-mapping-in-nhibernate)**: Add new class, and then reference it using a many to many relatinship:

```
class It{
  A a;
  B b;
  C c;
}
class A{
  public virtual ISet<It> Relationship{set;get;}
}
```

However, I fear NHibernate might add an ID to 'It' on its own, or I that I might have to use a composite key (which isn't a good practice).

**Two**: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519084/fluent-nhibernate-many-to-many-mapping-with-3-classes). Which uses two separate collections on each class to model a three way relationship. But I think there will be an unnecessary effort to access the information later, plus it's a bit trickier to get the mapping right.

Instead, I figured I could do something like:

```
class A{
  IList<Tuple<C, D>> ARelationship;
}
```

That way you have the two references together from the beginning. But I haven't been able to find an example on how to do such mapping (a list of tuples). I found you could define an [ICompositeUserType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560895/listtuplet1-t2-t3-to-database-mapping) subclass to do that, however I don't fully understand how that works or how to use it to solve my problem.

My **question**(s) being: What's the best way to model such a relationship? 
If it's by using a separate class (method one), what's the best way to map it from the viewpoint of each class, and how to map the newly defined class? 
If it's by using a list of tuples, is it possible to map it without using ICompositeUserType? How? 
Also, I might have missed the answer by doing incorrect Google searches. Are there other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Three-way associations in NHibernate

There are two main ways of mapping ternary (a.k.a. three-way) associations in NHibernate.

1. `map` using `index-many-to-many` (a.k.a. `map-key-many-to-many`), and
2. collection with `composite-element` contents.

---

#### `map` using `index-many-to-many`

From the [documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ternary):

> There are two possible approaches to mapping a ternary association. One approach is to use composite elements (discussed below). Another is to use an `IDictionary` with an association as its index:
>
> ```
> <map name="Contracts" lazy="true">
>     <key column="employer_id"/>
>     <index-many-to-many column="employee_id" class="Employee"/>
>     <one-to-many class="Contract"/>
> </map>
>
> <map name="Connections" lazy="true">
>     <key column="node1_id"/>
>     <index-many-to-many column="node2_id" class="Node"/>
>     <many-to-many column="connection_id" class="Connection"/>
> </map>
> ```

When possible, I enjoy using the `IDictionary` approach pictured above.  This approach is a good fit when there is some kind of unique constraint on two of the references in the association table, like so:

```
create table It (
    A_id int not null,
    B_id int not null,
    C_id int not null,
    primary key (A_id, B_id),
    foreign key (A_id) references A (Id),
    foreign key (B_id) references B (Id),
    foreign key (C_id) references C (Id)
);
```

This allows you to create an object model that looks like:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual IDictionary<B, C> RelatedCEntities { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping for this would look like:

```
<map name="RelatedCEntities" table="It">
    <key column="A_id"/>
    <index-many-to-many column="B_id" class="B"/>
    <many-to-many column="C_id" class="C"/>
</map>
```

You never end up having to map `It` as an entity.  It's simply used as the association table for the `many-to-many`.

---

#### collection with `composite-element`

If there is no unique constraint, we can look [a little lower in the documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#components-incollections) for composite elements:

> Collections of components are supported (eg. an array of type `Name`). Declare your component collection by replacing the `<element>` tag with a `<composite-element>` tag.
>
> ```
> <set name="SomeNames" table="some_names" lazy="true">
>     <key column="id"/>
>     <composite-element class="Eg.Name, Eg"> <!-- class attribute required -->
>         <property name="Initial"/>
>         <property name="First"/>
>         <property name="Last"/>
>     </composite-element>
> </set>
> ```
>
> Note: if you define an `ISet` of composite elements, it is very important to implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` correctly.
>
> ...
>
> Even ternary (or quaternary, etc) associations are possible:
>
> ```
> <class name="Order" .... >
>     ....
>     <set name="PurchasedItems" table="purchase_items" lazy="true">
>         <key column="order_id">
>         <composite-element class="OrderLine">
>             <many-to-one name="PurchaseDetails class="Purchase"/>
>             <many-to-one name="Item" class="Item"/>
>         </composite-element>
>     </set>
> </class>
> ```

I don't think you'll be able to use `Tuple<T1, T2>` because it is immutable - properties `Item1` and `Item2` have no setters.  But it is trivial to create a small class with two properties for this purpose.

Comment: The dictionary approach does not work for me:
`[Id_A, Id_B, Id_C]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2] 
[1, 2, 2]`
'A' is storing the dictionary, B and C are not dictionary key candidates. An ISet<Tuple<B, C>> best models the requirement: No repeated rows, but B can be repeated as C changes, or C can be repeated as B changes.